# Android app login, connection in background

Tags: android, authentication

I'm having trouble making my app ready for android 3.x and 4.
The simple way I used for logging in is not possible in these versions, and I did some research but can't find a way to do it right.

The problem is that since Android 3.0, you can't connect to the internet with an httpclient in the main thread. I can't find a way to do this in the background, that the user clicks 'login' and in a child activity the information is checked with the server, and the user is shown the dashboard. Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) to do the Background Processes.

**IntentService** From the Docs

> IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous
>   requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests
>   through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed,
>   handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself
>   when it runs out of work.

**AsyncTask** From the Docs

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class
>   allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI
>   thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.